# React project anchor tag doesn't work in iPhone Safari when i deploy; only works on chrome

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Below are my two components im using; when using chrome the anchor id's are redirected to its corresponding component; but when using safari its not working.

Links.jsx

```
const Links = () => {
  const items = ["Homepage", "Our Mission", "Services", "About", "Contact"];

  return (
    <motion.div className="links" variants={variants}>
      {items.map((item) => (
        <motion.a
          href={`#${item}`}
          key={item}
          variants={itemVariants}
          whileHover={{ scale: 1.1 }}
          whileTap={{ scale: 0.95 }}
        >
          {item}
        </motion.a>
      ))}
    </motion.div>
  );
};
```

App.jsx

```
const App = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <section id="Homepage">
        <Navbar />
        <Hero />
      </section>
      <section id="Our Mission">
        <Services />
      </section>
      <section id="Services">
        <VideoBg type="portfolio" />
      </section>
      <Portfolio />
      <section id="About">
        <About />
      </section>
      <section id="Contact">
        <Contact />
      </section>
    </div>
  );
};
```

I tried adding a / infront of the id but it doesnt work.

Comment: Can you try the react `<a/>` component instead of `<motion.a/>`?